# Get order-id on Firegento PDF protected function _insertFooter(&$page)

Tags: extensions, magento-1, invoice, pdf

I need to disable some footer information (bank account information) in Firegento pdf invoice depending on payment method. in the file `FireGento/Pdf/Model/Engine/Abstract.php` on line 891 ff there is the code I want do disable.

So I tried `$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()` but of course there is no order-id or order information given to `protected function _insertFooter(&$page)`.

So, how can I get `$order` in the `protected function _insertFooter(&$page)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you do not edit the extension files, but [write your own engine](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/wiki/FAQs#i-do-not-like-the-standard-engines---how-can-i-write-my-own-engine) and make the customisation there.

Regarding your question, the answer is rather simple: you can just use `$this->getOrder()` in order to get the order instance. This variable is set in the specific engine implementations like [`FireGento_Pdf_Model_Engine_Invoice_Default`](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/blob/master/src/app/code/community/FireGento/Pdf/Model/Engine/Invoice/Default.php#L70).